# Happy New Year 2024 free drinks party

Tags: calculation-puzzle

You have many friends and they like to drink*.  So you decided to throw a whole-day party and invite them for a party with a free drink every hour.

During the first hour one friend comes and you offer him a drink.

During the second hour two more friends come and you serve them a drink each, as well as to the first friend.

During the third hour three friends come and you offer them a drink and to all others.

During the fourth hour, you guess it, four more friends come and all people present get a free drink.

This continues until the 22nd hour when 22 more friends come and each of them as well as all those who came earlier receive a drink.

At this point, just after serving the last guest, you run out of drinks.

Nobody left the party.  How many drinks did you serve?

Hint

> Drink responsibly.  Excess alcohol can harm your health and well-being.

Comment: Where does that asterisk in the first sentence go to?

Comment: To the bottom, but that was converted to a hint later :-(

Comment: Would you like me to make it not be a hint?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not really a puzzle.  A math problem at best.

Comment: Don't bother.  Just now I cast the last vote to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All told, I have served

> $\frac{22×23×24}{6} = 2024$ drinks!
>  In the $n$'th hour, $n$ new friends arrive to the party, so the sequence of numbers of drinks I serve each hour is the triangular numbers $\binom{n+2}{2}$, and the running sum of these are the tetrahedral numbers $\binom{n+3}{3}$, where $n = 21$ instead of $22$ since the first drink is served in the first hour.

Happy New Year!